# Hide elements while changing slide in swiper js

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

I am using Swiper js for slides on the page. each slide has another image element positioned part inside the slide image and a part outside of it. so Whenever slide changes the part outside the slide can be seen.

I tries to use `overflow: hidden` for different classes of swiper js but did not work.

Here is the link you can check the slider: https://project-instock.netlify.app/index1.html#0

Comment: Why don't you use [scroll-snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts) rules?

Comment: How can scroll-snap hide the img elements when the slide change?

Comment: @DiD can you explain? As far I know scroll-snap is used to allow support for touch on smartphones. and scroll one section in at a time.

Comment: @tru-shar The scrolling script is a little unusual on my macbook. When moving on the touchpad with bit of velocity it scroll two frames at once.In addition, scroll-snap works much more efficiently on mobile devices.

Comment: With this touchpad movement on a normal page, the page would scroll 1/4-1/3 screen. That is, the scroll-snap would leave page on initial frame, but script moves down two frames.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by adding `fadeEffect: { crossFade: true, }`.

Initially, the script was

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.mySwiper5', {
effect: 'fade',
centeredSlides: true,
pagination: {
el: '.swiper-pagination',
clickable: true,
},
autoplay: {
delay: 7000,
disableOnInteraction: false,
},
});
```

Which has fade effect enabled but did not mention the kind of fade.